# SSH to Ubuntu tablet over USB?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, usb, ssh

I have a tablet running Ubuntu 9.04 with a USB connection to a host computer. (Ideally the host is running Windows, but if absolutely necessary I could switch the host to be Ubuntu also.)

I want to be able to SSH into the device without RS-232, WiFi, or other network connection. What software combination and setup do I need to make this happen?

Basically, I'd love the be able to have the equivalent of `adb shell`, but for when the tablet is running pure Ubuntu, not Android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up USB networking on the tablet http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/USB_Networking#Debian.2C_Ubuntu_and_others
assign ip addresses to the tablet and to your pc from the same private subnet